# Could not write ,you may be over quota: Bad file descriptor

Tags: php, web-hosting

When I edit uploaded file in cpanel of lankahost.net, can't save changes.

> Could not write
>   “/home/public_html/testing/application/config/database.php”, you may
>   be over quota: Bad file descriptor

Can you help?

Comment: Contact your hosting provider. Either there is a problem with their systems or it is just what it says: you have a quota on the disk space you can use (all/most hosting providers enforce a quota to their users) and you just reached it. Delete some big files to make room or ask the provider for more room. Not an issue you can solve by asking on [so], anyway.

Comment: ok i will ask thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your disk is full free some space on your server